# Insert Procedure with IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

I have procedure which i want to upgrade 
it is inserting new record for client in pickup data table before insert it is checking if new record for this client was inserted this month if yes it not inserting new record

i am trying to update it  so it will check if client StatusID in (1,2,6). So far i have this

```
alter PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPickup
    @ClientID int, --Required ClientID and PickupDate
    @PickupDate date 
AS
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Pickup 
                  WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
                    AND MONTH(PickupDate) = MONTH(@PickupDate) 
                    AND YEAR(PickupDate) = YEAR(@PickupDate) )
if exists (select * from clients where statusid in (1,2,6))
      INSERT INTO Pickup (ClientID, PickupDate)
      VALUES (@ClientID, @PickupDate)
```

however it is not right it still inserting record if for example client  with statusid = 5 or 3 or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not filtered your `clients` table by the `@ClientID` in your second `IF EXISTS` statement, hence it's not working as expected.  Try:

```
if exists (select * from clients where statusid in (1,2,6) AND ClientID = @ClientID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation and BEGIN/END wrappers can go a long way toward spotting issues in queries. I've added the check to `ClientID` and also made your test against `PickupDate` sargable (in case there's an index now or will be one in the future).

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.Pickup WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
    AND PickupDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @PickupDate), 0)
    AND PickupDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @PickupDate)+1, 0)
)
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM dbo.clients WHERE ClientID = @ClientID 
      AND statusid IN (1,2,6)
  )
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.Pickup (ClientID, PickupDate)
      VALUES (@ClientID, @PickupDate);
  END
END
```

Of course you can also do this without all the nested `IF` tests:

```
INSERT dbo.Pickup(ClientID, PickupDate)
  SELECT @ClientID, @PickupDate
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.clients WHERE ...
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Pickup WHERE ...
    );
```